# Adicionando classe current para o menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com o problema no meu JS ele esta adicionando a classe Current para todas as #li.

## html

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="sobre"><a href="/sobre">Sobre</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## jquery

```
alert(window.location.pathname);
$("#navlist li").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href")==window.location.pathname)
        $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça a seguinte alteração, não estava dando certo porque na tag `<li>` não existe o atributo **href** e com o `.children()` ele pega o elemento filho que nesse caso seria o `<a>` que possui o atributo **href**

```
alert(window.location.pathname);
$("#navlist li").each(function(){
    if($(this).children().attr("href")==window.location.pathname)
        $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Para esse `if` precisas de saber o `href` do *link* / *ancora*. Assim no teu seletor falta o ultimo passo que é dentro de cada `<li>` ir procurar a ancora `<a>` e adicionar uma classe.

Para isso podes usar o [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) que aceita um seletor CSS e procura nos descendentes do elemento inicial retornando o primeiro elemento que encontrar. Depois só tens de adicionar a classe ao elemento certo (`li` ou `a` consoante queiras).

```
$("#navlist li").each(function(){
    var $ancora = $(this).find('a');
    if($ancora.attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
        $(this).addClass("current");
        // ou $ancora.addClass("current"); se a classe fôr para adicionar ao link
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Já foram citadas ótimas soluções, mesmo assim segue abaixo minha contribuição.

Uma maneira interessante de resolver isso seria utilizar um [**Attribute Contains Selector**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) Um Seletor um pouco mais especifico.

```
 $("#navlist li a[href='"+window.location.pathname+"']").parent().addClass("current");
```

> NOTA: Conforme o discutido [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) e eu concluímos que o desenvolvedor
>   ao utilizar esta solução deve atentar-se a não escrever URLs absolutas
>   nos `href`  pois se tornariam incompatíveis com
>   `window.location.pathname`